# CRT heap debugging on Windows MS VC++ 2005

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2005, heap-corruption

I enabled heap debugging because of a memory leak error I started seeing in somebody else's code and I pinned down the problem (at least, so I think) to the destructor of a class, right after the call to the `delete []` below.

```
MyClass::~MyClass() {
    delete [] my_class_member_;
}
```

Now I confirmed that my_class_member_ which is an array of pointers to objects of a struct, say, `MyStruct`, has been allocated property using `new []` so I am not sure what is causing this leak? Here's what the `new []` call looks like:

```
delete [] my_class_member_;
my_class_member_ = new MyStruct[somesize_];
```

Next, the struct `MyStruct` is also relatively simple and is as follows (stripped down):

```
struct MyStruct {
    MyStruct() {}
    ~MyStruct() {
        for( PtrList<PClass>::iterator it(ps); it.more(); it.next() ) {
            delete it.cur();
        }
        for( PtrList<RClass>::iterator it(rs); it.more(); it.next() ) {
            delete it.cur();
        }
        delete shift;
    }
    PtrList<PClass> ps;
    PtrList<RClass> rs;
};
```

Now `PtrList` is a list of pointers (a built-in type of the application devkit we're using).. I am pretty certain that can't be at fault. Anyways, is anything out of whack that anybody notices here?? Appreciate any insight..

Comment: Have you followed the **Rule of Three**? From the information you present it is not clear whether you do so.You need to provide a *copy constructor* and *copy assignment operator* which do a deep copy of your dynamically allocated member.If you don't do so and if both these operators are not `private` and not left undefined then You cannot be sure that they are not being used at all and this is where your problem lies.

Comment: Thanks you might be on to something.. I am looking into that.

Comment: I read the post on Rule of Three, but my understanding is that if no copies/assignments are done, it should be safe the way it is, am I right?

Comment: Yes, and I quote again *"if both these operators are not private and not left undefined then You cannot be sure that they are not being used at all"*

Comment: Actually I see many assignments being done in the code on the struct like MyStruct s = my_class_member_[someindex]; I am guessing this might lead to a lot of issues, so I'll add only an assignment operator and see if that fixes it. I assume that the Rule applies also to structs? Thanks again for the excellent response! Kindly add as an answer and I'll accept right away.

Comment: ^ Typo: I meant I saw statements like MyStruct& s = my_class_member_[someindex];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comment as an answer as requested by OP.

Have you followed the ***[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)***?
From the information you present it is not clear whether you do so.You need to provide a ***copy constructor*** and ***copy assignment operator*** which do a ***deep copy*** of your dynamically allocated member.If you don't do so and if both these operators are not `private` and not left undefined then You cannot be sure that they are not being used at all and this is where your problem lies